# Catching a specific element when performing axios.get in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There is an element which i want to capture and assign it to lastid when performing a axios.get call when hitting URL - "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/products/". I am not getting how i can catch that one single element once which is "ldd" (as shown in JSON format) and assign it to vue.js script lastid variable.

```
[
  {
    "ActualPrice": 275, 
    "Category": "Beauty", 
    "ImageURL": "https://beautyme.jpg", 
    "OfferPercentage": 50, 
    "ProductName": "Fogg Deo", 
    "ProductURL": "https://nico.com", 
    "StrikedPrice": 550, 
    "ldd": "5bdd04934d395947f9c04237"
  }, 
  {
    "ActualPrice": 229, 
    "Category": "Beauty", 
    "ImageURL": "https://beautyme.jpg", 
    "OfferPercentage": 50, 
    "ProductName": "Marco, 150ml (Pack of 2)", 
    "ProductURL": "https://nico.com", 
    "StrikedPrice": 460, 
    "ldd": "5bdd04934d395947f9c04237"
  }, 
]
<script>
        var app5 = new Vue({
        el: '#app-5',
        delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
        data: {
            message: [],
            ld: 0,
        },
        methods: {
            loadmore: function () {
              axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/products/'+ld)
              .then(response => {
                this.message.push(...response.data);
                lastid = "5bdd04934d395947f9c04237"; //I want to update lastid
                });
            }
        },
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Did you try `lastid = this.message[this.message.length -1].ldd` if you are getting ordered data ?

Comment: @C2486 - Buddy thank you very much. Your solution worked.

Comment: it was very basic in javascript